# 2009 Corolla Center Console Cup Holder Insert won't stay in place

Tags: corolla, interior

I just purchased a 2009 Corolla and the center console cup holder divider was missing. [I found one on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/122316405808?_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) (pictured there) and received it today. Though it fits, it doesn't stay in place; it just sits in place with nothing to hold it down. Is it supposed to be glued down or held in place by some other means? What does the manufacturer do to keep it in there? Am I missing a bracket or pin?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the chances of your 2009 Corolla ever being a collectors item are vanishingly small, originality is not a concern.  Grab some red 3M double sided tape at your FLAPS and stick it down.

FLAPS == Friendly Local Auto Parts Store